# c++ error undefined reference error

Tags: c++, error-handling

I cant seem to figure out where im going wrong.I keep getting the error

```
undefined reference to Process::Process(std::string,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)
```

Me definition in the header file as follows

`public:
    Proccess(){}
    Proccess(string n, int arrtime, int prior, int a, int totalTick, int e = -1, int run = 0,int r = -1,int wait = 0);
    inline string Name() const {return name;}
    inline int    Arrival() const {return arrival;}
    inline int    End() const {return end;}
    inline int    Ready() const {return ready;}
    inline int    Running() const {return running;}
    inline int    Waiting() const {return waiting;}
    inline int    Age() const {return age;}
    inline int    Priority() const {return priority;}`

then in my cpp file i have this. My data types match up so i know that isnt the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Proccess::Proccess(string n, int arrtime, int prior, int a, int totalTick, int e, int run , int r ,int wait )
: name(n), arrival(arrtime), priority(prior), age(a), totalTickets(totalTick), end(e), running(run), ready(r),
  waiting(wait){}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you compile the file that contains the second constructor?

Comment: Is the code used from a file in the same project as the one that contains that class?

Comment: Yes the code is in the same project as the one with the class. I'm compiling with the following command "g++ -std=c++11 TicketSystem.cpp -o run" . TicketSystem's header file includes the header file i showed part of above which is process.h.